# PFX File not reading in application when published on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, x509certificate, pfx

I have an application which is reading a PFX file and sent across a network for authentication.

I have developed the application and the application is working perfectly when run from VisualStudio 2013. When run it gets loaded with IIS Express and everything works perfectly including reading the pfx file.

Now, When I publish this into my webserver(IIS7) its unable to fetch the Certificate from the PFX file.
The error which I get is

```
Failed to extract the X509 certificate
```

I tried giving Permissions to files, removed authentication and almost tried everything which might block IIS from reading the file. But still im getting this error.

Why is it behaving like this, ie It works perfectly in IIS Express and doesn't work form IIS7.

Comment: Does the PFX have a password?

Comment: Yes. The file name and password is already called

Comment: Is it self-signed cert or from a CA?

Comment: I think its from a CA. When I set the ApplicationPools LoadUserProfile to true, my PFX problem got solved. Now i have another problem ie "A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority" even though i have added three CA certificates in the certificates appropriate folders.

Comment: Sounds like its not installed correctly and you need to repair. How was the cert generated? Cause it would of have to been generated from that server.